# error: UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_user.username

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to register a new user so wheen I seed data I get this error

**return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_user.username**

model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

# custom manager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', "Male"),
    ('F', "Female"),
    ('O', "Other"),
)


class User(AbstractUser):
    #username = None
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default='1990-01-01')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='img/users', null=True, verbose_name=""
    )
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    objects = UserManager()

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not (self.is_staff or self.is_superuser):
            password = self.password
            if password is not None:
                self.set_password(password)
            super(User, self).save(**kwargs)
            name = f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
            Profile.objects.create(
                name=name, dob=self.date_of_birth, user=self)
            return self
        else:
            return super(User, self).save(**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse_lazy,reverse
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm,UserLoginForm

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
def get_success_urls(request):
    """
    Handle Success Url After Login
    """
    if 'next' in request.GET and request.GET['next'] != '':
        return request.GET['netx']
    else:
        return reverse('candidates:home')

def login(request):
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')

    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                auth.login(request, form.get_user())
                return HttpResponseRedirect(get_success_urls(request))
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html',context)


def user_registration(request):
    """
    Handle user registration
    """
    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form = form.save()
        return redirect('accounts:login.html')
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/user-registration.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from .models import User

class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        UserCreationForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['gender'].required = True
        self.fields['first_name'].label = "First Name :"
        self.fields['last_name'].label = "Last Name :"
        self.fields['email'].label = "Email :"
        self.fields['password1'].label = "Password"
        self.fields['password2'].label = " Confirm Password"
        self.fields['gender'].label = "Gender"
        self.fields['phone'].label = "Phone"
        self.fields['date_of_birth'].label = "Date Of Birth"

        self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs.update(
            {
                'placeholder': 'Enter First Name',
            }
        )
        self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs.update(
            {
                'placeholder': 'Enter Last Name',
            }
        )
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update(
            {
                'placeholder': 'Enter Email',
            }
        )
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update(
            {
                'placeholder': 'Enter Password',
            }
        )
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update(
            {
                'placeholder': 'Confirm Password',
            }
        )
        self.fields['phone'].widget.attrs.update(
            {
                'placeholder': 'Enter Phone',
            }
        )
        self.fields['date_of_birth'].widget.attrs.update(
            {
                'placeholder': 'Enter Date Of Birth',
            }

        )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone',
                  'password1', 'password2', 'gender', 'date_of_birth']
        error_messages = {
            "first_name": {"required": "First name is required", "max_length": "Name is too long"},
            "last_name": {"required": "Last name is required", "max_length": "Last Name is too long"},
            "gender": {"required": "Gender is required"},
        }

    def clean_gender(self):
        gender = self.cleaned_data.get('gender')
        if not gender:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Gender is required")
        return gender

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = UserCreationForm.save(self, commit=False)
        user.role = "user"
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user



class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', })
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        strip=False, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password', }))

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if email and password:
            self.user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                raise forms.ValidationError("User Does not exist")

            if not user.check_password(password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Password is not Match")

            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError("User is not Active")
        return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_user(self):
        return self.user
```

What is causing such an error? I researched similar posts on this platform but each case is unique.

> can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's what the error says.  You have set up using email addresses as the username and unique = True.  So you can't have 2 users with the same email address. Try using a different email address.  Does the superuser use the same email as the user your are trying to sign up?